# Suddenly my website front page was not found!

Tags: 6

My websites richtown.ae, and hannahaicah.com suddenly are not showing the front page; the rest of the pages is working fine. My hosting provider changed the php.ini file this morning, due to problems with PDO. Can anybody tell me what happened?

I also changed the path for the front page but nothing happened.

Comment: Your site is [currently down](http://isitup.org/richtown.ae) so there's not much anyone here can do. Try putting some nonsense characters in the root .htaccess file. If you don't get a 500 error when visiting the site next time, then .htaccess isn't being processed (most likely because of an `AllowOverride None` directive in the vhost file)

Comment: @Clive, its up NOW :)

Comment: Check your status report,
 are you using a view to place content in frontPage?

Comment: hi clive, can you please check this website too hannahaicah.com it also not show the front page

Comment: Hi pan, yes i am using views in front page

Comment: the path of the view works? e.g richtown.ae/frontpage?

Comment: weird stuff on your menu , some links have ?q=path and some dont, clean urls enabled?

Comment: pan can you please tell me whats wrong with my two website not showing the front page hannahaicah.com, richtown.ae

Comment: @pan chrono, like you doubted my views are not showing you can check through this url news.richtown.ae

Comment: hi guys i found the problem when i type without www it works perfect, what should i do now

Comment: @Bala Now you've resolved this question, you should answer it and check it off.  Then you can open another question regarding the non-canonicalisation of your sites :)

Comment: And again i had the same issue and it solved by changing the php.ini file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your .htaccess and the setup of your subdomain.richtown.ae...
frontpage on a subdomain?

```
# If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
# can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
# URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
#
# To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
# (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
# uncomment the following:
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
# RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
#
# To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
# (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
# uncomment the following:
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
# RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```