# Recently front page to Drupal 6 site not found

Tags: 6

For the past month or so, I have been experiencing intermittent problems with the front page of my Drupal site not being found. I have noticed that this has been asked before but none of the suggestions is working for me. As far as I know, the hosting provider hasn't changed anything and neither have I (other than applying module updates as needed). When I log in, the front page display fine and seems to work for awhile for both logged in and anonymous users. Then it will disappear again some time later. Any ideas as to what I should be looking at to fix this? I would suspect perhaps it might be a recent module update but I would figure more people might be experiencing this problem. When the page doesn't display, I see a 406 error in the drupal log.

Thanks.

Comment: check this it happens to me but not always - read the comments http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/65206/suddenly-my-website-front-page-was-not-found

Comment: Did changing .htaccess file make a difference? I am not sure how directing users to using either a www prefixed domain or not would make a difference. Can you explain why it would?

Comment: I don't know exactly, but it solved my issue. Have you configured your .htaccess file properly. redirect domain.com to www.domain.com may be it will solve your issue -  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]